# Mock endpoint ignores message

Tags: java, mocking, apache-camel, jboss-arquillian

I have the following test class:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Inject
    @Uri("mock:repositoryRoute")
    private ProducerTemplate producer;

    @Inject
    @Mock("direct:someStart")
    private MockEndpoint endRoute;

    @Inject
    private ModelCamelContext modelContext;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        modelContext.start();
    }

    @After
    public void stopContext() throws Exception {
        modelContext.stop();
    }

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> deploy() {
      // deployment code
    }



    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        endRoute.expectedMessageCount(1);
        producer.sendBody("direct:someStart", someBody);
        endRoute.assertIsSatisfied();
    }


    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        endRoute.expectedMessageCount(1);
        producer.sendBody("direct:someStart", someBody);
        endRoute.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

After I run the test class:

- First test passes
- Second test fails, even though it goes through the route.

However, if I run the test class with *test1* ignored, then *test2* passes.

Could someone please explain the reason for this behaviour and advise me how I can fix it?

**EDIT**
While debugging MockEndpoint and having I have noticed that counter field changes unexpectedly changes from number of tests run to zero while performing one test. So I wonder whether there is one more instance of MockEndpoint created?

Comment: Could be it be related to your \@Before and \@After methods? Since I don't know what's going on in those methods, then its hard to say. I'm not familiar with Arquillian though so I'm not sure.

Comment: I mean I don't know what's going on in the *modelContext.start()* and *modelContext.stop()* methods.

Comment: @Craig, well, this methods are from DefaultCamelContext

Comment: Ok. I notice that you added the '@Inject' and the '@Mock'. In Mockito, you add '@Mock' to the things you want to Mock and '@InjectMocks' to the classes you want to inject those '@Mocks' into. Therefore, it doesn't make since to have '@Inject' on something you want to mock since it is a mock and nothing will be injected into it.

Comment: @Craig I am not sure why (probably it has something to do with camel-cdi stuff) but when I remove '@Inject' the route fails to initialize with
//Either 'uri' or 'ref' must be specified on: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext// message.

Comment: @Craig I have also tried to remove modelContext.stop(). And when I did so all of the tests passed/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86975/discussion-between-anjenson-and-craig).

Comment: Sorry I'm at lunch at the moment. On my phone so can't help much

Comment: Is the second test failing because it's receiving 0 or 2 messages? If it's receiving 2, try adding `endRoute.reset()` to your `@After` method.

Comment: @mdnghtblue it actually receives 0 messages